# Linksys AE3000 install on linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, wifi, kernel-modules, cisco

I bought a Linksys AE3000 wireless adapter hoping I could use it on my Ubuntu 12.04 box. I found a [website](http://geekniggle.blogspot.com/2012/07/cisco-linksys-ae3000-wifi-usb-dongle.html) that walked through using it, but it didn't work. I edited `rtusb_dev_id.c` to add:

and then did `sudo make -j10` and got:

> ```
> make -C tools
> make[1]: Entering directory `/home/eduardop911/Desktop/Linux/DPO_RT3573_LinuxSTA_V2.5.0.0/tools'
> gcc -g bin2h.c -o bin2h
> cp -f os/linux/Makefile.6 /home/eduardop911/Desktop/Linux/DPO_RT3573_LinuxSTA_V2.5.0.0/os/linux/Makefile
> make -C /lib/modules/3.2.0-39-generic/build SUBDIRS=/home/eduardop911/Desktop/Linux/DPO_RT3573_LinuxSTA_V2.5.0.0/os/linux modules
> make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/eduardop911/Desktop/Linux/DPO_RT3573_LinuxSTA_V2.5.0.0/tools'
> /home/eduardop911/Desktop/Linux/DPO_RT3573_LinuxSTA_V2.5.0.0/tools/bin2h
> make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-39-generic'
> CC [M] /home/eduardop911/Desktop/Linux/DPO_RT3573_LinuxSTA_V2.5.0.0/os/linux/../../common/rtmp_mcu.o
> LD [M] /home/eduardop911/Desktop/Linux/DPO_RT3573_LinuxSTA_V2.5.0.0/os/linux/rt3573sta.o
> Building modules, stage 2.
> MODPOST 1 modules
> LD [M] /home/eduardop911/Desktop/Linux/DPO_RT3573_LinuxSTA_V2.5.0.0/os/linux/rt3573sta.ko
> make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-39-generic'
> cp -f /home/eduardop911/Desktop/Linux/DPO_RT3573_LinuxSTA_V2.5.0.0/os/linux/rt3573sta.ko
> ```
>
> /tftpboot

then i did the
sudo make install:

```
> make -C
> /home/eduardop911/Desktop/Linux/DPO_RT3573_LinuxSTA_V2.5.0.0/os/linux
> -f Makefile.6 install mkdir: cannot create directory `/etc/Wireless': File exists make[1]: Entering directory
> `/home/eduardop911/Desktop/Linux/DPO_RT3573_LinuxSTA_V2.5.0.0/os/linux'
> rm -rf /etc/Wireless/RT2870STA mkdir /etc/Wireless/RT2870STA cp
> /home/eduardop911/Desktop/Linux/DPO_RT3573_LinuxSTA_V2.5.0.0/RT2870STA.dat
> /etc/Wireless/RT2870STA/. install -d
> /lib/modules/3.2.0-39-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ install -m
> 644 -c rt3573sta.ko
> /lib/modules/3.2.0-39-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/
> /sbin/depmod -a 3.2.0-39-generic make[1]: Leaving directory
> `/home/eduardop911/Desktop/Linux/DPO_RT3573_LinuxSTA_V2.5.0.0/os/linux'
```

I finished with:

```
sudo depmod -a 
sudo modprobe -v rt3573sta
```

but was not able to get the light to light up. Any suggestions?

Comment: Your link says: *"Sorry, the page you were looking for in this blog does not exist."*  In general if you really are buying hardware for use with linux, it's a good idea to check around first for stuff that is known to work out of the box with in tree kernel drivers (which there are plenty of comparable devices in this case that do).  Once you get into compiling out of tree stuff from here there and everywhere you are just begging for hassles.  That said, have you tried to use the device, eg. via `ifconfig` or iw tools?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is probably that your `modprobe` had no effect because an existing module with the same name was already loaded into the kernel (the old one, before your patch).

You must do an `modprobe -r rt3573sta` first before `modprobe rt3573sta`, else the new module won't be loaded. That explains why it works after rebooting your machine.

Answer (score 0):

After doing all steps above and rebooting, the drivers started working.

Answer (score -3):

Try using Edimax 7822 uac driver installed on linux and then put your device it worked with me fine